# Testing an ssh key to github.com via ssh command

Tags: github, ssh-keys, deploy-keys

[Github's documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection) explains that there is this command that you can run to validate a key:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I have also experimented and seen that you can run

```
ssh -T git@github.com verify
```

to get some info. Is there a command you can exec to get the same information you would get the same output as when you try to get a shell (with no extra args to ssh)?

Comment: `ssh git@github.com`?

Comment: There is no command in there